# what is the least expensive way of running a simple script/command in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to set up a cron job in aws, to run a simple script to do a health check or check if there are new updates in RSS feed. I know I can use a curl command to check/download for this. is lambda cheapest option. is there any cheaper option than this, to set up a cron job , which runs and checks periodically?

```
curl -Is http://www.example.com | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in thinking of setting up a Lambda on a Cron Schedule. Right now there isn't any other service cheaper, looking at a few alternatives they're multiples the cost:

ECS
EKS
EC2
FarGate

Lambda is free for the first 1 million calls and is purpose built to be run for 5-15mins and the most popular ways are either a Cron schedule or Http Endpoint.

Comment: Plus, you only pay for the number of milliseconds that it runs!

Comment: @John - thanks. one follow up question. I am aware of cold start delay in lambda, but that should still be faster than starting an fargate task right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the performance of Fargate, but given the coldstart is typically related to the language runtime (especially for Java), they would both have similar startup delays. Given your task (health check, RSS feed), a coldstart delay would not be a problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - thanks, that is helpful. I wonder if someone has measured differences between the cold starts between different language runtime